# Close button not closing the popup box overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is the html for the my ul,and on click of anchor tag data will be loaded from  the other file tab2.html .

```
<ul class="list-unstyled " id="dist-tabs">
    <li class="col-xs-3 student item ">
        <a href="./tabs/tab2.html #1">
          shimla
        </a>                   
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 staff item">
       <a href="./tabs/tab2.html #2">
          dharamshala
       </a>
     </li>
</ul>

<div id="dist-container">           
</div>
```

Following is the content for the tab2.html , which will be loaded through ajax.

```
<div class="popup-overlay" id="1">
    <div class="popup-box">         
          <h4>Name 1</h4>       
        <span class="close-btn">x close</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="popup-overlay" id="2">
    <div class="popup-box">         
          <h4>Name 2</h4>       
        <span class="close-btn">x close</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every thing is working fine, popup opens just fine. But on click of close button with class="close-btn", the popup-box doesn't close

Following is the js i am using for the purpose stated above .

```
var containerId = '#dist-container';
var tabsId = '#dist-tabs';

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(tabsId + ' A').click(function(){
     loadTab($(this));        
        return false;
    });
});

function loadTab(tabObj){
    if(!tabObj || !tabObj.length){ return; }
    $(containerId).addClass('loading');
    $(containerId).fadeOut('fast');

    $(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('href'), function(){
        $(containerId).removeClass('loading');
        $(containerId).fadeIn('fast');
    });
   $(".close-btn").click(function(){
      $(containerId).fadeOut('fast');
   });
}
```

I have tried a lot of code for popup through ajax but not successful so far. So please help me out

Comment: Can you share the fiddle for this ?

Comment: Works well here: http://jsfiddle.net/k45a7x8m/
Have you checked chrome console?